# String compared to label text javascript

Tags: javascript

I am create a webiste and I basically need to see if the strings match in order to mark result as correct ( green ) or wrong ( red ).

Problem that I am having is that it's always turned to red, even though the strings are both same, I have no clue where I went wrong.

Here is the code

```
var checkedButton = getCheckedRadio(document.getElementsByName("answer"));
        var id = checkedButton.id;
        if(id=="answer1"){
            var answer1 = document.getElementById("answer1text");
            if(rightAnswer == answer1.innerHTML){
                    answer1.style.color = "#33FF00";
            } 
            else{
                    answer1.style.color = "red";
            }   

        }
        else if(id=="answer2"){...
```

I have checked `rightAnswer`, and `answer1.innerHTML` with `alert()` and it gives same results, but it doesn't work when i try to compare them... Also tried with `===` operator, same thing...

**HTML CODE EDIT**

```
<form>
            <div id="left">
                <div id="a1">
                    <input type="radio" name="answer" value="" checked id="answer1">
                    <label id="answer1text">Odgovor na prvo pitanje</label>
                </div>
                <div id="a2">
                    <input type="radio" name="answer" value="" id="answer2">
                    <label id="answer2text">Odgovor na prvo pitanje</label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="right">
                <div id="a3">
                    <input type="radio" name="answer" value="" id="answer3">
                    <label id="answer3text">Odgovor na prvo pitanje</label>
                </div>
                <div id="a4">
                    <input type="radio" name="answer" value="" id="answer4">
                    <label id="answer4text">Odgovor na prvo pitanje</label>
                </div>
            </div>...
```

**EDIT 2 - Whole Javascript**

```
        <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    var counter = 1;
    var split;
    var rightAnswer;
    function potvrdi(){
            counter = getCookie("counter");

            if(counter == "")counter = 1;

            var potvrdi = document.getElementById("gmedu").innerHTML;
            if(potvrdi == "Potvrdi"){
                checkAnswer();
                document.getElementById("gmedu").innerHTML = "Dalje";

            }
            else{
                alert(counter);
                setCookie("counter",(parseInt(counter)+1));
                doSplit();
                document.getElementById("gmedu").innerHTML = "Potvrdi";
                document.getElementById("answer1text").style.color = "black";
                document.getElementById("answer2text").style.color = "black";
                document.getElementById("answer3text").style.color = "black";
                document.getElementById("answer4text").style.color = "black";
            }

        return false;
    }
    function setCookie(cname, cvalue) {
        document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + "; ";
    }
    function getCookie(cname) {
        var name = cname + "=";
        var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
        for(var i=0; i<ca.length; i++) {
            var c = ca[i];
            while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1);
            if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) return c.substring(name.length,c.length);
        }
        return "";
    }
    function doSplit(){
        var text = "1.\r\n"+...\\here is a huge string of text   
        split = text.split(/\b\d+\./);
        var split1 = split[counter].split(/\n\w+\)/);
        rightAnswer = split1[1];
        split1 = randomizeAnswers(split1);
        document.getElementById("question").innerHTML = split1[0];
        document.getElementById("answer1text").innerHTML = split1[1];
        document.getElementById("answer2text").innerHTML = split1[2];
        if(split1.length > 3){
            document.getElementById("answer3text").innerHTML = split1[3];
            document.getElementById("a3").style.visibility = "visible";
            }
        else
            document.getElementById("a3").style.visibility = "hidden";
        if(split1.length > 4){
            document.getElementById("answer4text").innerHTML = split1[4];
            document.getElementById("a4").style.visibility = "visible";
        }
        else
            document.getElementById("a4").style.visibility = "hidden";
}
    function randomizeAnswers(split1){
        var length = split1.length-1;
        var random = (parseInt(Math.random()*length))+1;
        var tmp = split1[1];
        split1[1] = split1[random];
        split1[random] = tmp;
        return split1;
    }
    function checkAnswer(){
        var checkedButton = getCheckedRadio(document.getElementsByName("answer"));
        var id = checkedButton.id;
        if(id=="answer1"){
            var answer1 = document.getElementById("answer1text");
            console.log(answer1.innerHTML) 
            console.log(rightAnswer)
            if(rightAnswer === document.getElementById("answer1text").value){
                    answer1.style.color = "#33FF00";
                    alert("TACNO!");
            } 
            else{
                    answer1.style.color = "red";
                    alert("NETACNO!");
            }   

        }
        else if(id=="answer2"){
            var answer2 = document.getElementById("answer2text");
            if(rightAnswer == (answer2.innerHTML)) 
                answer2.style.color = "#33FF00";
            else    
                answer2.style.color = "red";
        }
        else if(id=="answer3"){
            var answer3 = document.getElementById("answer3text");
            if(rightAnswer == (answer3.innerHTML)) 
                answer3.style.color = "#33FF00";
            else    
                answer3.style.color = "red";
        }
        else if(id=="answer4"){
            var answer4 = document.getElementById("answer4text");
            if(rightAnswer == (answer4.innerHTML)) 
                answer4.style.color = "#33FF00";
            else    
                answer4.style.color = "red";
        }
    }
    function getCheckedRadio(radio_group) {
        for (var i = 0; i < radio_group.length; i++) {
            var button = radio_group[i];
            if (button.checked) {
                return button;
            }
        }
        return undefined;
    }

</script>
```

Comment: you should use .value() instead of innerHTML

Comment: what is _answer1text_ and can you check what return `console.log(answer1.innerHTML)` and `console.log(rightAnswer)`?

Comment: @JamesonYu tried that, doesn't work either, also tried textContent, doesn't work

Comment: @Grundy answer1text is a label element. console log returns string values normaly, nothing suspicious. Can it be because i am using Edge browser?

Comment: Add your HTML code please.

Comment: where you get _rightAnswer_? also you can check length for this strings, possibly one of them have some additional symbols, like space

Comment: @Grundy rightAnswer is saved when answer strings are assigned to label. It should't be a problem because i litearly do this: rightAnswer = string;
document.getElementById("answer1text").innerHTML = string;
So when i retrieve it i shoudl get the same string, or at least i think so. Im noob at javascript

Comment: I turned your code into a jsfiddle and I guess it works. It turns the first radio button green and alerts "TACNO!"...
http://jsfiddle.net/wb4ugde5/

Comment: Now i am really confused xD thanks a lot Henrik!

Comment: @HenrikNielsen I wasn't being sarcastic, i meant to say thanks for the time that you've put in :)

Comment: @HenrikNielsen Do you have any clue why this won't work in browser?

Comment: Not really - the only thing I changed was this line where you got the comment wrong:
var text = "1.\r\n"+...\\here is a huge string of text   
(it should have been forward slashes)
But I assume the comment error was only in your example code...

Comment: @HenrikNielsen yes, only in the code  example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As i see, your problem with this two lines

```
var text = "1.\r\n"+...\\here is a huge string of text   
split = text.split(/\b\d+\./);
```

after splitting in `split[1]` not just text, but text started with `\r\n`,
**But!** in html serial spaced symbols reduced to just one, and in your case `innerHTML` would be start whith `\n`, that's why your comparing false.

I see at least two way for fix this

1. change split expression, to

   ```
   split = text.split(/\b\d+\.\r\n/);
   ```
2. replace this symbols before comparing

   ```
   rightAnswer.replace(/\r|\n/g,"") == answer1.innerHTML.replace(/\r|\n/g,"")
   ```

Comment: Thanks, this fixed my problem!

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `textContent` to get the text of label instead of `innerHTML` :

```
if(rightAnswer == answer1.textContent){
     answer1.style.color = "#33FF00";
}else{
     answer1.style.color = "red";
}
```

**NOTE :** Maybe the problem is `rightAnswer` you should show us from where you get this value.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for trying but look at my comment, i said that i have tried that :D

Comment: Add rest of javascript code so we can make a live example.

Comment: Locally, from my computer, inside browser.

Comment: I mean there's no event that i can see in code so how you call the functions in your code for checking the answer, ( maybe `checkAnswer();`).

Comment: It's via an onClick event, there is a button in the html

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use `textContent` instead of `innerHTML` and `trim` it :

```
if(rightAnswer == answer1.textContent.trim()){
...
}
```